# Can I route traffic to Google App Engine with Load Balancer/URL Mapper or...?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I moved several legacy services onto Google App Engine with the intention of proxying traffic to them.  In fact, I had *hoped* that I could split routes via the Url Mapper, for example:

```
example.org/route1 => appengine-service1
example.ort/route2 => appengine-service2
example.org/route3 => storage-backend
example.org/route4 => compute-engine1
```

... etc.

However, it looks like I can only attach GCE backends or Cloud Storage backends to a Load Balancer and URL Mapper.  Is there no way to attach a Google App Engine as a backend to a Load Balancer?  Do I really need to set up my own reverse proxy, or else have the thing directly connected directly to the internet with a real custom hostname (registered with Webmaster Central, and all that)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time Google HTTP Load Balancers do not support services such as App Engine in GA.

There is an Alpha program that you ***might*** be able to sign up for to preview these features (Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, App Engine (Standard and Flex)). Contact your account manager for more details.

Comment: Are there other ways of doing this in the Google Cloud?  It would be a major limitation to deploying a microservice architecture if the intention is to publish all these services directly to external endpoints with verified hostnames.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can achieve this by Serverless NEG with HTTPS load balancer. See Serverless NEG release status in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62660953/4185100. I will update that post when it is in GA.

Answer (score 0):

#### You dont have to register a hostname to use it.

You can tell GC that you are the owner of certain domain by verifying it, like they teach [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/verify-domain-name). You shoud configure both on Webmaster Central and Google Cloud.

Just follow the tutorial and you would see it becomes available after a few hours (24h). Then you would be able to route it to app engine, cloud run or any other service. Let me know if you have any problem

Comment: So when you say "route it", are you saying it can be done with the Google Load Balancer?  I don't see any way to do that, other than to install my own reverse proxy.

Comment: (sorry, I edited the title to make it clearer what I want to do---ultimately I need to split traffic that's going to an existing hostname and its aliases)

Comment: Acording to your corrections, you are trying to split some traffic based on the http/s level. Therefore, to configure the load balancer in such way use the official documentation [here] (https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https?hl=en_US)

Short answer is yes, you can use the load balancer or you can implement your own reverse proxy. I prefer the frst option but remember to configure correctly your domain provider.

Comment: The link you provided seems to indicate that it is NOT possible to connect to an App Engine: "A backend service or backend bucket distributes requests to healthy backends (instance groups containing Compute Engine VMs, NEGs containing GKE containers), or Cloud Storage buckets."

Comment: Also, as per "instance groups": "An instance group is a collection of virtual machine (VM) instances that you can manage as a single entity." (i.e. not an AppEngine) https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups